# Pyinstaller command not found

Tags: linux, python

(I am on Linux, and use SuperUser as Stackoverflow told me to go here!)

I want to use pyinstaller, so I followed their documententation:

```
pip install pyinstaller  
pyinstaller my_script_name.py
```

pip install says:

```
Successfully installed altgraph-0.15 dis3-0.1.2 future-0.16.0 macholib-1.9 pefile-2017.11.5 pyinstaller-3.3.1 setuptools-39.0.1
```

But when I run pyinstaller  it says:

```
pyinstaller: command not found
```

I tried the same with pip3, same result.

Comment: Try `pip show pyinstaller`. It should provide you information where it's installed. Then make sure you have the location in your path if you want to call it like you did.

Comment: /home/yoran/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (pip3) or /home/yoran/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (pip)

Comment: @JaroslavKucera, however I can not find any file who marks as 'launch me'or the start.,

Answer (score 1):

1. find where is pyinstaller

   ```
   find / -name "pyinstaller"
   ```

   the result looks like

   ```
   /usr/local/python3/bin/pyinstaller
   ```
2. copy it to `/usr/bin/pyinstaller` (where linux automatically finds commands)

   ```
   cp /usr/local/python3/bin/pyinstaller /usr/bin/pyinstaller3.cp
   ```

   Then you can run pyinstaller!

p.s.: If you don't want to copy the file you can directly run `pyinstaller` through

```
/usr/local/python3/bin/pyinstaller
```

Hope it helps!

p.p.s.:

Check the doc, [Verifying the installation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#verifying-the-installation)

Comment: rather than copy, a simlink will do the job.